# Migrating a Web Deployment Project from Visual Studio 2010 to 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013

I've been working on a web development/deployment project (.wdproj) in Visual Studio 2010 that is used in production. Word is that in Visual Studio 2012, 2013, and probably 2015, web development/deployment projects are no longer compatible.

I've searched a myriad of sites trying to find some way to convert/migrate/upgrade my project so that I can work with it in **at least** Visual Studio 2013 but I have not had any luck. I figured something like this would be very common but that is far from the case.

**How do I convert, migrate, or upgrade my current Visual Studio 2010 *web development/deployment project (.wdproj)* to be compatible in Visual Studio 2013?**

I use the .wdproj to compile all my .cs files to the code-behind of my site. Is there a different way of doing this now? If so, where is the documentation for this?

Comment: Have you looked at the Publish feature of newer VS versions. This is not a project type, but VS acting on definitions stored within the project. It will – with various options – perform compilation and deployment (eg. to a staging folder).

Comment: I'm watching a video right now from Scott Hanselman @ www.asp.net. His example includes getting a .publishsettings file from his azure server but this is another awful demonstration because not everybody has azure.

Comment: When you first use Build | Publish VS will prompt you and create the necessary `.pubxml` files. You don't need any other files for a publish to filesystem (from where one can copy to the test/production environment).

Comment: Will the new system allow me to build and publish single files at a time or does it require me to publish the entire site?

Comment: No idea, I've only used it with whole sites (but that also ensures consistency). Of course, publish to staging and then copy means you could just copy only some files from staging...